# Why am I getting a null result when reading an XML file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following code:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {

        var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            //read the file and get results
            getDomicilesFromXML(xhr); //separate function (this is not the problem)

        };
        xhr.open('GET', TheXMLFile.xml', false);
        xhr.send();

    }
```

This function is called in the initialize function for the web page. "TheXMLFile" is an XML file that is in the root project directory of my website. It doesn't seem to be reading the file, as the result is always null. Am I missing something?

Comment: I´m not sure if that is async or not, but why is the alert before the send?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was just testing something. It failed, of course. I'll take it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onreadystatechange` is fired *repeatedly* several times before the response is ready to be read. You need to check `xhr.readyState` to see whether it's ready, and `status` to see whether it was successful.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 0 || (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300)) {
            //read the file and get results
            getDomicilesFromXML(xhr); //separate function (this is not the problem)
        }
    }
};
```

(The `xhr.status == 0` is a workaround I'm not sure we still need these days, some browsers [used to?] do that with cached responses.)

---

I would recommend removing the `false` from your `open` call. Forcing the HTTP request to be synchronous is almost never necessary, and locks up the UI of the browser during the request.

Comment: I believe this worked; however, I'm getting another error now. Thanks!